# DbExpression Binding requires an input expression

Tags: c#, linq

Why is casting a byte array to ienumerable float throwing this error?

```
public List<myModel> Get()
{
    List<myModel> data;            
    using (var db = new MyEntities())
    {
        var query = db.Images.OrderBy(x => x.ID).Select(x => new myModel
        {
            Id = x.ID,
            Name = x.Name,
            Bytes = x.Bytes,        
            BytesToFloat = (IEnumerable<float>)x.Bytes
        });
        data = query.ToList();
    }
    return data;
}

public class myModel
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Byte[] Bytes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<float> BytesToFloat { get; set; } 
}
```

I am getting this error:

> {"DbExpressionBinding requires an input expression with a collection ResultType.\r\nParameter name: input"}

Comment: x is the Image entity(Image table from the sql server db) x.Bytes is a Byte[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't explicitly cast a byte array to an `IEnumerable<float>`. Try using [`.Cast<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406(v=vs.100).aspx) instead:

```
BytesToFloat = (IEnumerable<float>)bytes.Cast<float>()
```

Now your problem is you cannot call .Cast<> against a database query so you should convert it to a list then run the cast. So your function becomes this:

```
public List<myModel> Get()
{
    using (var db = new myEntities())
    {
        return db.Images.OrderBy(x => x.Id==1).ToList()
            .Select(x => new myModel
            {
                Id = x.Id,
                Name = x.Name,
                Bytes = x.Bytes,        
                BytesToFloat = (IEnumerable<float>)x.Bytes.Cast<float>()
            }).ToList();

    }
}
```